# Does trapper/hunter harvest reflect abundance or community composition?

Tags: ecology

I'm working on a study where a single professional trapper removes furbearers and corvids (who the trapper is changes annually). I would suspect that the composition of the harvest would be strongly influenced by the individual's trapping style, ie. how and where they choose to set their choice of traps, as none of this is regulated. However, others argue that the harvest is reflective of species abundance and community composition. I'm having difficulty finding sources for either argument that aren't fisheries-centric. Can anyone suggest any?

Comment: It would be more reflective of relative abundance, rather than actual abundance unless you have 100% catchability.  Comparatively these concepts for furbearer traps should be similar those in fisheries related to catchability and selectivity.  This is my opinion  as a  hobbyist trapper and professional fisheries biologist.